# Struct and interface relationships in Go, passing a struct while waiting for an interface

Tags: go, struct, interface, abstraction

Let's say I have struct as that holds an interface;

```
type Client struct {
     httpClient oop.HTTPClientInterface
}
```

Let's say I have an another struct as follows:

```
type HTTPImpl struct {
     httpNotify HTTPNotificationInterface
}
```

this struct is initialized with the following function and single parameter which is interface.

```
func NewHTTPImpl(httpNotify HTTPNotificationInterface) {}
```

And assuming that this struct HTTPImpl implements all the methods defined inside but there's no explicitly saying or mapping between `oop.HTTPClientInterface` and HTTPImpl. Method names and signatures are same.

So, this is the part I don't understand,

Let's say `Client` struct is initialized and I want to set `httpClient`. Code below works. I don't know how.

```
1- c := NewClient()
2- c.Client = NewHTTPImpl(c)
3- if _, ok := c.Client.(*HTTPImpl)
```

How does this work? I don't understand. How does the code line 2 and line 3 work? Casting and passing a struct while waiting for an interface. And when I remove one of the interface method implementation from HTTPImpl, code gets underlined with a red color and requires it to be implemented.

What's the exact relationship here between interfaces and structs in Go here?

Comment: Please come up with a full and understandable example. You probably should also use proper names, e.g. interfaces are not named ...Interface but _er and "implementations" do not carry a ...Impl suffix. Basically this is covered in depth in the Tour of Go and in countless online resources so redo "Methods and interfaces" https://go.dev/tour/methods/1 ff which explains all this much better than a SO answer.

Comment: This is covered in [the tour](https://go.dev/tour/methods/9) and [the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Interface_types).

Answer (score -2):

It is called runtime polymorphism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_polymorphism

Runtime checks if the type being fed implements all the necessary methods described by the interface.

Your IDE is checking what would happen if the code run and it's marking that it would fail.

Comment: It is runtime polymorphism, but the checks happen at compile time, not run time. At run time, the type is already known to satisfy the interface.

Comment: it's the IDE showing the error. OP isn't running it.

Comment: I know, but the point stands. It's not "runtime checks", and it's not the IDE "checking what would happen if the code run". It's a compile-time check, so the IDE is checking what would happen if the code was compiled.